# static definition of a lambda in std::vector crashes in multi-threaded environment

Tags: multithreading, c++11, vector, lambda, static

This is the code snippet from a method in a class:

```
....
std::string sHelper (sKey);

// interface keys definition with corresponding code implemented as lambda
std::vector<InterfaceOptionsResolve> vKeywords =
{
    {
        "{Instrument}",
        [&] (const std::string sKeyword)
        {
            // sInstrument is a member in the class
            sHelper.replace(sHelper.find(sKeyword), sKeyword.size(), sInstrument);
        }
    },
    ....
};

// check each interface template keyword against the provided interface template name
for ( const auto &itKeyword : vKeywords )
{
    if ( strstr(sHelper.c_str(), itKeyword.sParameter.c_str()) )
    {
        // if the interface key was found replace it with the corresponding value
        itKeyword.oLambda(itKeyword.sParameter);
    }
}
....
```

In short words: In the method function I define a `std::vector` with a keyword and a lambda function which is executed for each matching keyword. I could have done several `if !strcmp(....) { the code from the lambda function }` but I prefer it like this.

When I change the definition of `std::vector<InterfaceOptionsResolve> vKeywords =` to `static std::vector....` then the application crashes horrible in a multi-threaded environment (Segmentation fault). I don't understand why. For me only the lambda code and `const std::string` are `static` but the access to the method variables via `[&]` should be done from the active scope.

Could someone explain me where I have the logical error?

Here the definition of `InterfaceOptionsResolve`:

```
typedef struct
{
    const std::string       sParameter;
    std::function<void(const std::string)>  oLambda;
} InterfaceOptionsResolve;
```

Comment: The lambda is the same for every keyword, so why generate loads of different types with identical code instead of just using a named function?!

Comment: @JonathanWakely: No, of course NOT! It is just a snippet! Each keyword has a completely different code!

Comment: Ah OK, I misunderstood. That doesn't change my answer below (which is why I put this unrelated comment as a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For me only the lambda code and `const std::string` are static but the access to the method variables via `[&]` should be done from the active scope.

No, the lambda expression runs when the static vector is first initialized, so the `[&]` capture will bind a reference to the `sHelper` in the *current* scope. When you next run the function, that `sHelper` is gone and there is a completely different object called `sHelper` in scope, but your static lambdas still refer to the old one.